# SoapUI Eclipse Plugin Freezes

Tags: eclipse, web-services, eclipse-plugin, soapui

I'm using soapUI eclipse plugin.

I open soapUI Navigator and create a new project. On the new project screen, I choose the location of the wsdl to generate test cases from.

After I click 'OK', the plugin starts loading the definitions. This is when it freezes.

I wasn't able to find any thing on the internet besides this 3 year old bug (which is the exact same issue I'm having, you can also see the screen shot of it): http://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs/522/

Does any one know any information regarding what causes it, is there a way around, etc.
I'm inside a corporate network, can access internet fine, but there are firewall restrictions etc.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this problem. I ended up using the HTTP Monitor plugins in eclipse, which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use eclipse Soupui plugin version 4.0.1 and it works fine.